# Computing apparent magnitude with Armadillo (C++)

Tags: c++, filter, armadillo, astronomy, ssp

I'm looking for someone very expert in using [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html) (C++). I am a wannabe astronomer and I'm trying to compute the ab apparent magnitude [m_ab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_magnitude) of a SSP (simple stellar population, a group of chemically homogeneus and coeval stars) in a specific filter of a telescope.

The input of the function `compute_ab`, which does this calculation, are the wavelength `wavelength` and the corresponding Spectral Energy Distribution `sed` of the SSP (basically it is the luminoisty of the SSP per unit wavelength, over a range of wavelength); the input `fresp` and `fwaves` are the throughput of the telescope (basically the filter in a certain band) and the corresponding wavelength range over which the througput is distributed. They are `std::vector<long double>` in 1D. What I need to output is a number, possibly a double or long double.

What I surely need to compute m_ab from these information is an interpolation, because the SED and the throughput can be at very different wavelengths; it is a convolution and an integration. Physically speaking, the passages I make in this function are correct, so I'm asking some help to use Armadillo, am I doing it correctly? How can I set the output as a double? Moreover, I'm getting this error right now, when I run my code:

```
    error: trapz(): length of X must equal the number of rows in Y when dim=0
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  trapz(): length of X must equal the number of rows in Y when dim=0
```

Here it is the function:

```
mat compute_ab(vector <long double> waves,vector <long double> sed, vector <long double> fwaves,vector <long double> fresp){

  colvec filter_interp;

  colvec csed = conv_to< colvec >::from(sed);
  colvec cwaves = conv_to< colvec >::from(waves);
  colvec cfwaves = conv_to< colvec >::from(fwaves);
  colvec cfresp = conv_to< colvec >::from(fresp);

  arma::interp1(cfwaves,cfresp,cwaves,filter_interp);

  colvec filterSpec = arma::conv(filter_interp,csed);

  colvec i1 = arma::conv(filterSpec, cwaves);
  colvec i2 = arma::conv(filter_interp, 1./cwaves); 

  mat I1=arma::trapz(i1,cwaves);
  mat I2=arma::trapz(i2,cwaves);

  mat fnu=I1/I2/speedcunitas;
  mat mAB= -2.5 * log10(fnu) -48.6;
  return mAB;

}
```

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Regarding you error; I think you may need to add the "same" argument in the conv function,  see http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#conv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with this code and maybe a few operations that are not doing what you want.

---

1. You are coping the the input vectors, which can be very costly and is completely unnecessary. Change

```cpp
mat compute_ab(vector <long double> waves,vector <long double> sed, vector <long double> fwaves,vector <long double> fresp){
```

to

```cpp
mat compute_ab(const vector <long double>& waves,const vector <long double>& sed, const vector <long double>& fwaves,const vector <long double>& fresp){
```

---

2. `colvec` and `vec` are the same thing. Column vectors of doubles. You can use just `vec`, if you want. You are converting the `std::vector<double>` to `arma::colvec` using `conv_to<colvec>::from`. This is fine, but again you are copying the elements. Since you just want to perform linear algebra operation with these `std::vector<double>` inputs and they are only used inside the function, you can do better.

For instance, consider the code below

```cpp
std::vector<double> v;
v.push_back(2.4);
v.push_back(-1.4);
v.push_back(10);

arma::vec c = arma::conv_to<arma::colvec>::from(v);
arma::colvec n;

std::cout << &c[0] << std::endl;
std::cout << &v[0] << std::endl;
```

The `cout`s will print the memory address of the first element in the original vector and in the converted vec, which are indeed diferente. A better approach is using a special constructor from `arma::vec` that initializes the vector from a memory address and tell it to not copy the elements. That is, change the `arma::vec c` line to

```cpp
arma::vec c = arma::vec(v.data(), v.size(), false);
```

The [`data` member](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/data/) of `std::vector` gives a pointer to its elements that we can pass to `arma::vec` constructor along the number of elements.
Now the `cout`s will print the same address for `&c[0]` and `&v[0]` confirming that the elements are not being copied.

---

3. Take a look in the output of your `arma::conv` calls. For instance, passing two input vectors each with 3 elements will result in a output vector with 5 elements. Look at the documentation of [`arma::conv`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#conv). Particularly, there is a third argument called "shape" that might be useful to you.

---

4. `arma::trapz( X, Y )` documentation says

> Compute the trapezoidal integral of Y with respect to spacing in X.
> X must be a vector; **its length must equal to the number of rows in Y**.

The dimensions of the inputs you are passing to `arma::trapz` don't match and you get the mentioned error. The reason is that the output of `arma::conv` is likely not what you expected and you probably want to pass "same" as the third argument of `arma::conv`.

---

TLDR;

My suggestion is that you print the result of each line in `compute_ab` to see if it is what you expect. If it is not, then look into that particular armadillo function's documentation. Do this and you will quickly get more confident using the armadillo library. Often a function in armadillo has several overloads.